# AOC cu34g2x monitor usb ports have stopped working

Tags: usb, display, usb-3

I've had the AOC cu34g2x 34in ultrawide for maybe 8 months now. It has been working perfectly and I have been using the monitor's usb hub to transfer my peripherals between my desktop and work laptop through the usbA to usbB cable. 2 days ago this stopped working. It seems plugging it into either computer yields no result and the lights on the keyboard/mouse don't even light up. I've tried unplugging everything and replugging it. Direct connect of mouse/keyboard to desktop works fine but the usbB doesn't even make the windows connection noise now. Anyone had this issue and get it fixed? I literally just threw the box out last week so I would really hate to have to attempt to replace this thing.

Comment: Can you try the monitor on a different computer? The tests you have done suggest that the monitor is the issue. Does it have a 1 year warranty?  Replace it under the warranty.

Comment: I've got it hooked to both the desktop and laptop. The monitor itself works on both, but the usb hub doesn't work on either now. Neither does the windows usb plugged in sound with it either. They both do it with the keyboard/mouse plugged directly in though. I'm wondering if maybe the usbB cable they provided is garbage so I'm at least going to order one of those first. I'm pretty sure it's still under warranty, but I know some companies complain if it's not in the original box and I literally just tossed it.

Comment: Just tried the full factory reset in the settings and that didn't work either. Should the keyboard and mouse still light up even if the usb hub cable isn't attached? I think I remember it still lighting up in the past during swapping the cable. If it should still get power then the whole hub is probably fried. If not, I'm hoping it's just the cablle